# Backbone Marionette save CollectionView and it's ChildViews for rerendering

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

So I have a collectionview which fetches data from an api. I would like to save this data so that users don't have to make additional Ajax calls when going back to the page, as they have already requested this data. The issue seems to be that Marionette destroys the collectionview's childviews and when trying to rerender, it tries to render views that have already been destroyed. How do I prevent the childviews from being destroyed?

Comment: I don't think you can stop the CollectionView from destroying it's children. That shouldn't cause an ajax request though. Are you making ajax requests from your child views? Can you post some code?

Comment: You seen to have two disjointed issues: 1. How to access data and 2. How to control the  ChildView lifecycle. Please, clarify your question and throwing in some code would be helpful.

Comment: I solved my problem. I attached my collection to my global app object which I was able to save from page to page and whenever I wanted to use previous data from my collection, I just passed it to my view.